# Return Linq to SQL association objects in list

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have the following Linq to SQL structure: I have the classes "Article" and "User". Each Article has a Seller (which is a User) and each User has many Articles. I solved that with an association.

[image]

And then I have an method Read(), which gets all Articles and returns it in a list.

```
public static List<Article> Read()
    {
        using (DataContext dbx = new DataContext())
        {    
            return dbx.Article.ToList();
        }
    }
```

So, the problem now is: When I use the list anywhere in my program and I want to access article.Seller, I get the following exception:

> Cannot access a disposed object

Okay, this seems legit, because I return the list and then DataContext is disposed. If I want to access the seller, it will be loaded from the database and thats not possible anymore with disposed DataContext.

So I solved that with lazy-loading and set the **DeferredLoadingEnabled** property to false.
To load the Seller, I used the **DataLoadOptions**.

```
public static List<Article> Read()
    {
        using (DataContext dbx = new DataContext())
        {
            dbx.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
            DataLoadOptions options = new DataLoadOptions();
            options.LoadWith<Article>(a => a.Seller);
            dbx.LoadOptions = options;

            return dbx.Article.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Okay, that works so far, but in one level only. Now I can access article.Seller, but if I'd like to get the other articles of that seller (article.Seller.Articles), I get null.
Just load with the articles of the Seller `options.LoadWith<User>(u => u.Articles);` I thought, but that is also not possible, because it would be endless.

Article -> Seller -> Articles -> each Article a Seller -> Articles -> again Seller -> ...

I get the exception

> Cycles not allowed in LoadOptions LoadWith type graph.

What I want, is a method to get all the articles with correct association objects, like shown in my first method.
The association objects should always be accessible, but only loaded from database when accessed.

This would be possible if I use the DataContext everywhere I need the list in the program and then work with the list only in the DataContext.
But that would be very laborious.

Have you guys any idea how to get access to the association objects without writing the code of my Read() method everywhere in my program I need the list?

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this in the past as well. The general practice is that you don't call `Dispose()` if you are going to allow deferred loading. In fact, calling `Dispose()` is not really required at all.

There is quite a lot written about whether or not to call `Dispose()` on the DataContext. You'll have to sift through it, but there's a nice article [here](http://leedumond.com/blog/about-disposing-the-datacontext/). Basically, because the DataContext manages its connections itself, it doesn't really have any connections that need to be disposed explicitly.